# Requerir certificado de cliente al acceder a una Url

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ssl, certificado

Estoy tratando de que cuando el cliente acceda a una determinada url le solicite un certificado de autenticación válido. Tengo las pruebas realizadas en Xampp y en servidor remoto Centos 7.9 Apache 2.4. El código lo he sacado de stackoverflow versiones en ingles. La estructura es la siguiente un directorio test con un script pagina_secreta.php. Un directorio entrada con un script index.php y un htaccess con la directiva SSLVerifyClient require. Al intentar llamar a pagina_secreta.php se requiere al archivo entrada/index.php y este debería solicitar el certificado de cliente para continuar y redirigir a pagina_secreta.php. No consigo hacerlo funcionar ni en xampp ni en mi servidor remoto. No se que me falta, que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy pasando por alto.

script: pagina_secreta.php (directorio principal test)

```html
<?php
/* Iniciamos el funcionamiento de las sesiones de PHP */
session_start();
/* Comprobamos si tenemos los datos del certificado */
if (!isset($_SESSION['certificado'])) {
  header('Location: https://sites.local/test/entrada/index.php');
  die("error lectura certificado");
}else{
    echo "error lectura certificado";
    exit;
}
/* A partir de aquí tenemos los datos del certificado "garantizados" */
echo "visualizando pagina secreta";
```

Script index.php en directorio entrada:

```html
<?php
/* Iniciamos el funcionamiento de las sesiones de PHP */
session_start();
/* Guardamos en una variable de sesión los datos del certificado */
$_SESSION['certificado'] = [
  'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'],
  'SSL_CLIENT_S_DN' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'],
  'SSL_CLIENT_V_END' => $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_END'],
];
/* Redirigimos a la página "pagina_secreta.php" fuera de "/entrada" */
echo $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'];
echo $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'];
echo $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_V_END']
header('Location: https://sites.local/test/pagina_secreta.php');
```

htaccess en directorio entrada (junto a index.php):

```html
SSLVerifyClient require
```

en el httpd-ssl.conf tengo las siguientes directivas:

```html
<Location test/entrada/>
        SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
        SSLVerifyDepth 10
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
</Location>
```

Por favor alguien me podría ayudar y decirme que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy pasando por alto. No funcionan los scripts y me sale un flamante error 403 que no tengo permisos de acceso. Gracias.
Un saludo,
Ramiro

Comment: Un *detallito*: ¿ El cliente desde el que estás probando tiene instalado un certificado válido para permitirte el acceso ?

Comment: En el servidor remoto si tiene su certificado y en el xampp tiene uno autofirmado que uso en local.

Answer (score 0):

despues de darle muchas vueltas la cosa era más sencilla de lo que pensaba. Estoy convencido de que habrá muchas formas incluso más elegantes y de mejor  aplicación. Esta es la que a mi me ha funcionado trabajando en xampp. Si alguien conoce alguna mejor, sería interesante que la expusiera. Lo he trabajado a nivel de servidor.

en el httpd.conf doy los permisos a las carpetas protegidas:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp73/htdocs/dominio/test/entrada">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp73/htdocs/dominio/inscripciones/vistas/test/entrada">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

En el httpd-ssl.conf en el VirtualHost

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp73/htdocs/dominio.com"
ServerName dominio.com:443
SSLEngine on
#---- Apunto a las carpetas de los certificados
SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp73/apache/crt/dominio.com/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp73/apache/crt/dominio.com/server.key"
#---- No requiero certificado en ningún area del servidor
SSLVerifyClient none
#---- Solicito el certificado en las localizaciones requeridas
<Location "/test/entrada">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted 
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
    SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>

<Location "/inscripciones/vistas/test/entrada">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted 
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
    SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
```

Reinicio el xampp y a funcionar, al entrar en el script pagina_secreta.php de la carpeta test, esta requiere el index.php que requiere un certificado. Este es solicitado y visualiza la totalidad de pagina_secreta.php o desde aqui redirecciono a ubicaciones protegidas del servidor ya que tengo los datos del certificado.

Previamente en el archivo windows/sistem32/drivers/etc/host tengo declarado el dominio.com contra 127.0.0.1 (localhost) y tenia creados los certificados correspondientes de dominio.com. De esta forma trabajo en local y https con su certificado de seguridad, ya que, sin esto y por mucho que se configure el servidor apache al no ser una dirección segura, de confianza, no admite ni siquierea llega a solicitar el certificado de seguridad.

Una anda"dura" de más o menos 10 días. No soy ningún experto en apache, pero si que desearía que la experiencia le sirviese a alguien.